# How to use ffmpeg .so file in Android application

Tags: android, ffmpeg, 32-bit

I have compiled ffmpeg code and generated .so files,
Then I put these .so files in jniLibs/armeabi/ folder.

To use it below code :

```
Controller.java
public class Controller {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("avutil");
        System.loadLibrary("swresample");
        System.loadLibrary("avcodec");
        System.loadLibrary("avformat");
        System.loadLibrary("swscale");
        System.loadLibrary("avfilter");
        System.loadLibrary("avdevice");
    }

    public static native void runffmpegCommand(String[] argv);

    public static void testFFMPEG(String[] strings) {
        runffmpegCommand(new String[]);
    }
}

ffmpeg_controller.c

#include <android/log.h>
#include "ffmpeg_Controller.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv);
JavaVM *sVm = NULL;
jint JNI_OnLoad( JavaVM* vm, void* reserved )
{
    sVm = vm;
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_test_Controller_runffmpegCommand(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobjectArray args)
{
    int i = 0;
    int argc = 0;
    char **argv = NULL;
    jstring *strr = NULL;
    if (args != NULL) {
        argc = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, args);
        argv = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * argc);
        strr = (jstring *) malloc(sizeof(jstring) * argc);
        for(i=0;i<argc;i++) { strr[i] = (jstring)(*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, args, i);
            argv[i] = (char *)(*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, strr[i], 0);
        }
    }
    main(argc, argv);
    for(i=0;i<argc;i++) {
     (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, strr[i], argv[i]);
    }
    free(argv);
    free(strr);
}

ffmpeg_controller.h

#include <jni.h>
#ifndef _Included_com_test_Controller
#define _Included_com_test_Controller
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_android_com_test_Controller_runffmpegCommand(JNIEnv *, jobject, jobjectArray);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

When I run this code it through error as below:

Logs:

2018-12-17 14:11:17.850 25598-25598/com.android.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.android.test, PID: 25598
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.android.test-1/lib/arm/libavutil.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:989)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1530)

Comment: this problem because you run application with  targetSdkVersion 26

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem her because you run application with targetSdkVersion 26 or more so the solution i think it's her look:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52951886/7055487

Answer (score 0):

The Exception is self-explain: "libavutil.so is 64-bit instead of 32-bit": you have copied a 64 bit library in a "jniLibs" subfolder that expects 32 bit libraries.

"jniLibs/armeabi" subfolder is for 32bit ONLY devices

Comment: I did same, but it does not work. jniLibs/armeabi/*.so  and jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/ *.so

Comment: If you copied libraries in a different subfolder, then the Exception should be different....