# Android NDK - Error Linking Shared library and JNI Wrapper

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to link a Shared Library that I generated with the NDK-Standalone toolchain on a different build machine. Then using that specific `.so` I put it on Android Studio. From there I created a `jni.h` file using javah which then helped me write the `.c` JNI for the function calls.

Followed this example [How do I compile any native (C, C++) library using NDK in the form of shared libraries](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-compile-any-native-C-C++-library-using-NDK-in-the-form-of-shared-libraries-or-binaries-having-Eclipse-or-Android-Studio-and-write-JNI-code-to-communicate-with-the-shared-libraries-or-binaries) .

`ndk-build` does compile and seems to work correctly but when trying to run the application on the phone I get a error at

```
static { 
    System.loadLibrary("testLib")
}
```

Saying that could not find `testLib.so` even though it is generated and in the `libs/armeabi-v7a/testLib.so` directory

**CURRENT ERROR:**

```
 01-31 14:41:53.779 19024-19024/com.jolopy.testing_02 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.jolopy.testing_02, PID: 19024
        java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.jolopy.testing_02-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.jolopy.testing_02-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "testLib.so"
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
            at com.jolopy.testing_02.TestLib.<clinit>(TestLib.java:6)
            at com.jolopy.testing_02.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
```

How I built the `.so` file:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -c -fPIC testLib.c -o test.o

arm-linux-androideabi-gcc test.o -o testing.so
```

From there I wrote a JNI wrapper class using `javah` which generated the `testing_Android.h` file. Which from there generated the testing_Android.c JNI wrapper that I'm using to call functions from my `testLib.c` library:

```
#include "testLib.h"
//Including Machine Generated Header
#include "testing_Android.h"
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_jolopy_testing_102_TestLib_testinglib_1Initialize
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
    (void)env;
    (void)obj;

    testing_Initialize();
}


JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_jolopy_testing_102_TestLib_testinglib_1Get_1Count
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
    (void)env;
    (void)obj;

    return(testing_Get_Count());
}


JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_jolopy_testing_102_TestLib_testinglib_1Get_1CurrentName
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong ptr, jint x){
    (void)env;
    (void)obj;

    return (testing_Get_CurrentName((char *)ptr , (int)x));

}
```

From there I have 5 files in the jni folder in Android which is where I run the ndk-build command from:

```
 testing.so | testing_Android.h | testing_Android.c | Application.mk | Android.mk
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH :=$(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := testLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := testing.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := testing_Android.c
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk:

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

Any suggestions or faults in my progress that you might see that I don't would be greatly appreciated.

-Cheers!

Comment: Your app is run on a 64-bit device, and it has some other (3rd party library, most likely) native component that has a 64-bit version. Until recently, the best practice would be to remove all 64-bit binaries from the APK. These days Google requires native 64-bit support from all applications in PlayStore. Therefore, the fix is to build and package your `libtestlib.so` in both **armeabi-v7a** and **arm64-v8a** flavours.

Comment: I guess that you redacted the actual filename, because the `lib` prefix is essential for Android to package and install your app correctly.

Comment: @AlexCohn that was one of the issues, but eventually got me to the right answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the ndk standalone toolchain, I used the ndk-build on my build machine which then generated the libs file I needed. From there I added the libs file with the contents of:

1. arm64-v8a
2. armeabi-v7a
3. x86
4. x86_64

Into my Android directory under src>main>jniLibs which then stored all the files and just added the command to my app build.gradle:

```
sourceSets.main{
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jniLibs'
    }
```

For ndk-build to work properly I had to include the jniWrapper.c file.

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH :=$(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := testing
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jniWrapper.c \
                    testLib.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk (I was testing with "all" but its unneeded):

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-23
APP_ABI := all
```

I know this is a work around solution but for some reason I could not figure out the toolchain to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Change below

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

to

```
APP_ABI := arm64-v8a
```

Because from your error logs, your device is arm64 ABI.

---

If you are starting a new Android NDK project, I would like to suggest you start from **Android Studio + CMake** tool chains, see here for my personal JniExample project based on Android Studio and CMake:

- https://github.com/russell-shizhen/JniExample
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52951886/8034839

Comment: Probably, especially if the app is supposed to run on API 19, the APP_ABI in Application.mk should list both `APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a`

Comment: @shizhen | @ Alex Cohn When I first started this project I remember using Android.mk + Application.mk which is the reason I was sticking to it over cmake. As for that change still nothing, I looked back at my directory and it seems the ndk-build is only creating the arm64-v8a .so files in libs. Even if APP_ABI := all . And reason on why it would only create the arm64-v8a and none of the rest? Could that be because of the way I formed the initial library?

Comment: [arm64-v8a] Prebuilt     : testing.so <= jni/
[arm64-v8a] Install       : testing.so => libs/arm64-v8a/testing.so
[x86_64] Prebuilt      : testing.so <= jni/
[x86_64] Install       : testing.so => libs/x86_64/testing.so
/home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android-strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `/home/user/Desktop/Testing_02/app/libs/x86_64/testing.so'
make: *** [/home/user/Desktop/Testing_02/app/libs/x86_64/testing.so] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file `/home/user/Desktop/Testing_02/app/libs/x86_64/testing.so'