# Adding 64 bit libraries in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, 64-bit

I have added below line of code to generate 64 bit lib files,But still so of the lib files are missing in 64 bit folders, How can I add those missing libraries? Do I need it add those libraries externally. [image]

Code:

```
ndk 

    {
      abiFilters "armeabi-v7a","arm64-v8a","x86","x86_64"

    }
```

Comment: You have to build those missing 64-bit libraries from source code, the `abiFilters` in your **app project** is actually to filter the ABIs, it is **NOT** to build those libraries if you don't provide `externalNativeBuild{}` and `CMakelist.txt` or the legacy ndk scritps.

Comment: How provide externalNativeBuild {}

Comment: @shizhen How can I provide 64 bit lib for this.

Comment: Do you have the corresponding source code?

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code#vanilla_cmake

Comment: Yes I have a source code.

Comment: For how to build native code, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/54471803/8034839 to see if it helps.

Comment: Is there any solution to add those missing libraries for 64 bit?

Comment: No.. u need to find out which SDK is not support for 64 bit and need to update the 64 bit support sdk version.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to generate your 64-bit so using

1. [Create](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/android-mk/hello-jni/jni/Application.mk) **Application.mk** inside your jni folder, where your native files are present
2. paste this **APP_ABI := all** in the **Application.mk** file. Save it.
3. Run **ndk-build** in the jni folder where your **Application.mk** is present.
4. If you've configured your =>**[Android](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/android-mk/hello-jni/jni/Android.mk).mk** with current modules you'll get so's for all the architecture in libs or jniLibs directory.

Comment: How to run ndk-build in the jni folder in Android Studio?

Comment: From command line:https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-build#ifc